# amCharts set legend label selected/unselected programmatically

Tags: amcharts

I have an amChart with 3 AmGraph. I need to enable/disable a graph programatically. I want that all graph are available but one of this disable, and only if the user click on the relative label the graph is show.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

To disable the graph on chart load, set it's [`hidden`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#hidden) property to `true` in chart config.

I.e.:

```
"graphs": [{
  // ...
  "hidden": true
}, ...]
```

To disable a graph via API, when the chart is already built, use the [`hideGraph()`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#hideGraph) method.

I.e.:

```
function hideGraphByIndex( index ) {
  chart.hideGraph( chart.graphs[ index ] );
}

function hideGraphById( id ) {
  chart.hideGraph( chart.getGraphById( id ) );
}
```